# How prevent copy unnecessary libraries on publish

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have three simple projects:

1. SampleApp.Cli1
2. SampleApp.Cli2
3. SampleApp.Lib

SampleApp.Cli1 use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration directly
SampleApp.Cli2 uses Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration through SampleApp.Lib

SampleApp.Cli1:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>../_out1</OutputPath>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>true</NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
</Project>
```

SampleApp.Cli2:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <OutputPath>../_out2</OutputPath>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>true</NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SampleApp.Lib\SampleApp.Lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

SampleApp.Lib:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Script for publishing:

```
@echo off

if exist "%~dp0_out1" (    
  rd "%~dp0_out1" /s /q  
)

if exist "%~dp0_out2" (    
  rd "%~dp0_out2" /s /q  
)

dotnet publish "%~dp0SampleApp.Cli1/SampleApp.Cli1.csproj" 
dotnet publish "%~dp0SampleApp.Cli2/SampleApp.Cli2.csproj"
```

**After build**

publish dir for SampleApp.Cli1 contains this files

```
web.config
SampleApp.Cli1.deps.json
SampleApp.Cli1.dll
SampleApp.Cli1.exe
SampleApp.Cli1.pdb
SampleApp.Cli1.runtimeconfig.json
```

publish dir for SampleApp.Cli2 contains this files

```
SampleApp.Lib.pdb
web.config
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
SampleApp.Cli2.deps.json
SampleApp.Cli2.dll
SampleApp.Cli2.exe
SampleApp.Cli2.pdb
SampleApp.Cli2.runtimeconfig.json
SampleApp.Lib.dll
```

**Question**

For some unknown for me reason, the publication understands that for SampleApp.Cli1 Microsoft.Extensions.* must be taken from the shared runtime(Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App), but does not understand the same for SampleApp.Cli2. Of course, I understand that the matter is most likely in SampleApp.Lib(in real application it was Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices).

In my situation, I have to build all libraries from sources that go into the publish folder. In real application Microsoft.Extensions.* libraries much more, and I would not really like to build all libraries from asp net core runtime.

Is any way to prevent copy(publish) Microsoft.Extensions.* libraries?

Sdk: 3.1.6

Comment: I had a very similar question but about .ddl.config files, take a look, might give you some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266725/disable-publish-of-ef-configuration-files-to-bin-folder

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for net-core. Or should?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Sorry, I missed the .NET Core.